# Problem data bind with ant table checkbox in vue

Tags: vue.js, ant-design-pro

I am new to vue ant design. I have a problem in data-bind in table checkbox.
I am using vue ant design table,
here my code

```
<a-table :columns="columns" :dataSource="data">
        <a-checkbox slot="col01" :checked="true" disabled  />
        <a-checkbox slot="col02" disabled />
</a-table>
```

columns design in Vue

```
   {
      title: "Col01",
      dataIndex: 'col01',    
      scopedSlots: { customRender: 'col01' }
    },
    {
      title: "Col02",
      dataIndex: 'col02',    
      scopedSlots: { customRender: 'col02' }
    }
```

Data bind in Vue

```
this.data.push({
    key: id,      
    col01:true,
    col02:element.satus

  });
```

Comment: You are not binding any data to checkboxes.
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox-1

Comment: yes you're correct I can able to fix this